# What's the fastest way to make Echoes (money) in Echo Bazaar?

Tags: fallen-london

What's the fastest way (fewest actions) to earn the most valuable commodities?

Answer (score 9):

The fastest way I've found so far is in Mahogany Hall; it requires a very high Persuasive skill. If you train the Louche Devil and teach him Philosophy, you'll get 111 Nevercold Brass Slivers per action and increase your Pygmalion quality. When Pygmalion reaches 17 or 18, you should be safe to take him out to a Society dinner, which gives you 1000 bonus slivers. ... You can then re-train him as often as you like to rack up lots of Echoes.

If you want to do it with your Dangerous, head to the third coil of the Labyrinth of Tigers.  "Avoid becoming an exhibit yourself" and "Fight back" for ~1 Echo per action.  (Most of the actions in the third coil earn ~1 Echo per action, but they require a very high Persuasive as well.)

Answer (score 5):

This is a difficult one to answer; given the link between Stories and Qualities, it will be different dependant on what is available to you.

As a general rule, completing a series of linked Stories will carry greater reward, but this can become inefficient if the Story is difficult for the determining Quality (failed attempts receive no monetary reward).

As for a specific tip; I would recommend searching the ruins in the forgotten quarter in the early game. The reward for the lowest level option is based solely on luck, and the cost of entry can be reasonably quickly reclaimed. 10 x relics @ 5p with a 50% success rate = 25p/adv.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you gain more valuable goods for completing more challenging stories. I would suggest focusing on a single statistic to unlock more rewarding stories. **Risky** and **Chancy** challenges seem to increases stats very quickly. When you want more loot per action, seek out easier stories.

Keeping on hand Second Chance items earned through social activities (Chess, etc) improves your chances of success in stories and is worth spending a few actions on.

Comment: I meant more concretely, which stories generate the most loot per action.

Comment: I wish I could answer more concretely. The existing wiki doesn't provide much analysis or guidance. The only forum topics I've found discussing money-making suggest you can make ~1 echo/turn in certain zones at high levels (80+). I haven't seen much solid spading of this game yet, beyond recording adventures and results.

Comment: Money isn't really worth much until the late game, and getting there will be much easier if you try to spread your growth out. It's very frustrating to be at 100 in one stat, only to find that you need 100 in all four to become a Person of Some Importance.

Answer (score 1):

I think most storylets are pretty well balanced. Labyrinth of Tigers and Mahogany Hall can give you about an Echo per success, but you also need stats of 90-100 to play.

So if all you're after is money, concentrate on one stat, because the rewards seem to be tied to that.

Also, many of the longer-term sequences (e.g. ones with Running Battle) can have big payoffs at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Gambling in the House of Chimes, in the Heart's Hazard room (need to be an Exceptional Friend and a Person of Some Importance), gives you about 1.5 echoes per action and an occasional epic success giving you 13 echoes and some suspicion.

Comment: 1.5 echoes per action _on average_, but still depends on your luck.

Comment: The normal success is +3.5 Echoes but the failure is -2 Echoes, so on the 50% success rate it has, it works out to a measly 0.75 Echoes per action on average (and the rare success is not THAT common).

Answer (score 1):

Once your stats are at a reasonable height, most grinding yields about an echo per action, but that's at straight bazaar prices where it doesn't matter if you're talking rostygold or glim or rats or whatever - but if you go with a grind that yields an improvable currency (foxfire candle stubs, glim, jade fragments, souls, stolen correspondence, lamplighter beeswax, whispered secrets, prisoner's honey, silk scraps, proscribed material, primordial shrieks, greyfields 1882) then grinding it high enough to bulk trade up through the chains to completion, and then selling finished products - Way more lucrative.

Answer (score 1):

Once you become a Person of Some Interest then you can do "Unfinished business" storylets at the main quality based locations like: Spite, Ladybones, Veilgarden, Watchmaker. The options that require 5 or 6 actions give random results but on average they give 1.5 Echoes. It's also less time consuming if you just need 2 clicks for 5 or 6 actions rather than 12 clicks  for 6x 1 action.

I've found that bulk converting upwards is actually action inefficient and unprofitable if you work out the rewards. It's not "lucrative" at all.

Comment: If you still have it lying around, would you mind sharing some of the math you used to find that bulk converting isn't the way to go? That would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Currently at Polythreme you can "Lurk in the eaves." The challenge level is quite high (broad 120 Shadowy), but:

- it has no menace on failure
- success gives 12 Romantic notions which make 1.2 Echoes at current Bazaar rate.

It seems also to be a good challenge for improving shadowy.

Answer (score 1):

The devs don't like people talking about Fatelocked content, for good reason, but if you choose to become a Spirifer, you gain access to a storylet that will provide you with roughly 1.74 echoes per action /on average/, if you use the Unfinished Business storylet in Spite to grind the requisite resource. Sometimes you'll get less than that and sometimes you'll get more than that; Unifinished Business storylets are unpredictable.

Keep in mind that this post assumes you're at the stat cap. The higher your stats are, the better your average will be.

If you haven't spent the Fate, or chose the other option, you can do the Affair of the Box Carousel; that's slightly less profitable at 1.6 Echoes Per Turn, but, y'know, it doesn't cost real money.

EDIT: If you're somehow looking at this and not at the official wiki's money-making guide page, every suggestion here is horrifically outdated. Even in the midgame there are now options that provide well over 4 echoes per action, and in the endgame you can hit 6EPA. Look [here](https://fallenlondon.wiki/wiki/Money-Making) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The Writer's Desk storylet is accessible from persuasion 10 in Veilgarden pays off very well, although the action cost per "cycle" is relatively great.

Anyway, according to some math I did, always publish as competent, write rapidly from 54 persuasion onwards, and frienzedly from 189 on, and the payoff per action is:

- 0.24 - 0.37, for persuasion 10-17
- 0.37, for persuasion 17-53
- 0.37 - 0.44, for persuasion 54-67
- 0.44, for persuasion 67-188
- 0.45 - 0.55, for persuasion 189-249
- 0.55, for persuasion 249+

Of course, long before you get that far, much better sources of income will become available.

Comment: There is no perception stat. Perhaps you are referring to Persuasion. Additionally, at 0.45 Echoes per action, there are significantly better options available for level 189 Persuasive... Pretty much everywhere you look at that point, honestly. Even at 50, you're probably going to be finding better options. At 100, as a Person of Some Importance, the Unfinished Business storylet opens up and you're even better off doing other things.

Comment: @Snowskeeper Yes, true. And thanks for the correction, I've edited my post :P

Comment: Sorry about the tone of my comment; I noticed it a few minutes after I wrote it, but by the time I'd finished editing, I'd passed the five-minute deadline. =S